# Cpanel doesn't change password

Tags: cpanel

I am trying to change a password using the cPanel API. cPanel doesn't change the password if the username and password are the same. Are there any other cases when cPanel doesn't change the password?

Comment: Maybe show us some code to show what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the log files for the reason

`/usr/local/cpanel/logs/access_log`

`/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to look at the regular user's documentation about changing passwords; it should point out what can't be done, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change password for cPanel users, it should be allowed from WHM,

You can check it from WHM >> Tweak settings >> Allow cPanel users to reset their password via email